# Deploy appengine endpoints to non-default version

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

According to the trusted tester documentation, there was an issue with endpoints that prevented them to be created when deploying to a "non-default" version. When 1.7.5 was released and endpoints graduated from trusted tester to "Experimental" we were told that this issue was fixed but couldn't be included in 1.7.5 (for timing reasons) and would be included in the next version.

Ok, the next version is already here (1.7.6) but still, if I deploy endpoints to a non-default version, they are not generated. Does anybody know if there is some specific setting that needs to be added to web.xml, appengine-web.xml or somewhere else? Or is this just that this feature was not included in 1.7.6 either.

From my point of view this is essential. I have an Android app based on requestfactory. If I replace my default version, the app will stop working. I need to deploy to a separate version, deploy a new Android app version pointing to this server version, and after some time when most of users have updated their Android app set that as default.

Thanks for any hints on this.

Comment: Well, I don't believe this is such a difficult question to answer for the people that work in the endpoints development (that told us after closing the trusted tester forum they would keep answering questions here). We put a lot of effort in migrating to endpoints and we have to keep that in a drawer until who knows when because we can't implement a proper migration strategy... Please give us some hint when will this be available.

Answer (score 1):

There's no ETA at the moment, but you can follow along on the tracking bug [here](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9147).

Answer (score 1):

This is now possible. You need to use a slightly different url to access the endpoints. Instead of `https://2.your_app_id.appspot.com`, **use `https://2-dot-your_app_id.appspot.com`** followed by the usual `/_ah/api/endpoint_name/version/…`

See [docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/test_deploy#accessing_backend_api_versions_deployed_to_non-default_application_versions).